# Is there a verb-form of "affirmative action"

Tags: single-word-requests

"Affirmative Action" is a noun sometimes used to describe legislation and government-programs which given women, and people of color, higher-priority in college admission decisions, than persons of white skin and males.

Is there a verb for "Affirmative Action?"

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't use it. It is very strongly associated with rants, mudslinging, and very low register propaganda. Although "affirmative actioning" has occasionally shown up as a participial adjective in edited works.

Comment: I can see *weighting* the choices you have to act on as a neutral term. Then we argue if it's good to rob Peter to pay Paul, but the term is clear and mild.

Answer (score 1):

In short, there are numerous words that can apply to the affirmative part of the clause, e.g. profiling, partiality, affinity, etc., but there's no single word that can be used for both words without stirring up a whole lot of contention from its supporters. That's because the terms racist and sexist are considered inaccurate merely because the policies are ostensibly the effort to counter those two very things.

However, in an honest forum, you could justly call it that, because affirmative action at its core is racism to counter historic racism, and sexism to counter historic sexism.

Answer (score 0):

As phrased in a *Smithsonian Magazine* article by Jackie Mansky, "The Origins of the Term "Affirmative Action'", 22 June [2016](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/learn-origins-term-affirmative-action-180959531/),

> …the origin of the term [*sc*. Affirmative Action] is *rooted with legalese in employment law*, explains Shirley J. Wilcher, the executive director for the American Association for Access, Equity and Diversity. To take an "affirmative action" was **to literally act affirmatively**—not allowing events to run their course but rather having the government (or employers) take an active role in treating employees fairly.

Aside from being what I concluded independently, Mansky's analysis is also born out by a sense of 'affirmatively' in [*OED*](https://oed.com/) (entry updated September 2012):

> Originally *U.S.* So as to affirm positively a particular position or policy, now esp. one that seeks to ensure minority groups, etc., are not discriminated against; so as to comply actively with such a policy. Frequently in **to act affirmatively**. Cf. *affirmative action* n. …

The "single word" verb corresponding to the noun 'affirmative action' is the legal *term*, 'to act affirmatively'. Being a legal term, it doesn't get any shorter than that, to my and others' regret.

Comment: This is correct in a legal context, but after reading some texts for a non-specialist readership it's striking how they take efforts not to use a verb form of affirmative action: you occasionally see forms such as "exercise racial preference" as well as lengthy phrases such as "apply affirmative action policies", but nothing short or snappy.

Comment: To fully understand how this term came to be used in this way, it may be helpful to consider that, in this context, it stands for the employment policies  that go beyond employers' merely abstaining from discrimination, i.e. beyond their obeying the antidiscrimination laws passively. The word *affirmative* is used in similar ways in other legal contexts (e.g. in the phrase *affirmative defence*).